# Period or colon?

Tags: punctuation, periods, colons

Say, I have the following sentence: "The Gaussian Sobolev spaces are as expected defined as follows" and then you do a definition environment after. The question is: how do you end "as follows"? With a period, or a colon?

I'd like to know if there is a strict English punctuation rule for this sentence.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own quesiton after the first six words.

Comment: Though the natural choice would be a colon, there are many situations where it is not recommended. One such exception could be where what 'follows' is an elaborate text, sometimes extending over more than a paragraph. Unless the "definition environment" this case is no longer than a sentence or at most two, it would be a good style practice to end the introductory with a period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question featured in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7480453#7480453).

If the definition follows immediately, I'd use "as follows:" with a colon.

> This is defined as follows:
>
> *(definition follows immediately)*

If the definition doesn't follow immediately, but after something else, I'd use "below." with a full stop.

> This is defined below.
>
> *(Some further discussion)*
> ...
> *(Definition is reached at some point)*

This isn't  grammar; it's a matter of style. But "X is defined as follows" indicates that the definition follows (immediately); "X is defined below" indicates that you will find it if you carry on reading.

"Below" **could** work for both.
But using a colon indicates "follows now" and a full-stop indicates "follows later".

Comment: It seems the answer in the chat cited was put in a slightly different way. It was not quite about the colon v. period. Even so here in a way.

Answer (score 9):

Punctuation isn't a matter of grammar, but, as R L Trask explains in his [‘Guide to Punctuation’](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node16.html#SECTION00051000000000000000),

> The colon is used to indicate that what follows it is an explanation
>   or elaboration of what precedes it. That is, having introduced some
>   topic in more general terms, you can use a colon  and go on to explain
>   that same topic in more specific terms.

So, yes, use a colon after *follows*, as you have done after your first six words.